# Why I cannot assign foreign key to this column?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, sqlyog

I've got a main table of users

```
create table `users` (
`id` int (10),
`first_name` varchar (192),
`last_name` varchar (192),
`password` varchar (96),
`phone` int (10),
`email` varchar (768),
`date_created` timestamp 
);
```

then I have a table of accounts, with foreign key user_id referring to main table of users

```
create table `accounts` (
`id` int (10),
`user_id` int (11),
`account_number` bigint (12),
`account_type` varchar (192),
`balance` double ,
`currency` varchar (9),
`date_created` timestamp 
);
```

and at the end, I have a table of transactions, however I'm not able to assign foreign key to user ID as well

```
create table `transactions` (
`id` int (10),
`user_id` int (11),
`from_account_id` int (12),
`to_account_id` int (11),
`amount` double ,
`currency` varchar (9),
`timestamp` timestamp 
 );
```

Whenever I try to add a foreign key to user_id from transactions table to refer to user_id in accounts, or id in users table I get same error both of the times.

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`bank`.`#sql-34ec_2`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-34ec_2_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`user_id`) REFERENCES `accounts` (`user_id`))

How can I avoid that, what else could I do to get the proper referring of particular cells?

Comment: Show the failed stmt u are using. Why nullable id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Truncate the all tables and than set the foreign key for this values.

Comment: Thank you, after I truncated all the relevant tables and added foreign keys afterwards, it passed!

Comment: Good now fix your table structure

Comment: If the given answer helped you please make it as correct answer thks

Answer (score 0):

Your data types might be different. 10 versus 11. Show code u are executing